# Do cookies and flash objects change with a new user account?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, privacy, cookie

I think Chrome's browser cookies and flash cookies are stored in

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/WritableRoot/#SharedObjects/
```

When I create a new user account in Ubuntu, do I now have a new Chrome browser with a new set of cookies, flash objects, etc...?

Some websites identify a user by their browser's cookies as well as the IP address. In case of the new user account in Ubuntu coupled with a new IP address, are such websites still able to identify me anyway?

Comment: You have new coockies, etc, but the same browser, OS, screen resolution, fonts, plugins, ...in short, sites may still be able to identify you as you.

Comment: Although Chrome will be available to you, the browser settings are specific to the user, thus the new account will not have the cookies history etc of the old account. If the site relies on cookies to identify you then they will not be able to identify you until you log in from the new account creating new cookies.

Comment: The site is Ebay.com, so I will have new user account, new cookies and flash objects, new screen resolution (will minimize Chrome window and not set it as full), new fonts, new user-agent and most importantly new static IP address and no DNS leakage. 

Do you think Ebay will still be able to identify this new setting as the old device?

Comment: Of course you do.

Answer (score 2):

I believe most websites today (at least those which don't want you to sell them your soul) use simple cookies for session management and user recognition, which isn't necessarily a bad thing. A cookie is like a text file, which may contain e.g. a unique code that is linked to your user account on a website and knowing this code tells the website that you are the legit, logged in user.

Where tracking becomes problematic is when it is not done by the first party you visit, which you probably want to recognize you when you come back later, but when third party domains (mostly ads and analytics services) place cookies or use other tracking methods. If those other domains are embedded into multiple different sites that you visit, they can track your surfing behaviour and create a detailed profile of you.

---

Given your question, I guess so far I haven't really told you any news, but I thought I'd sum this up again anyway.

Now when you create a new Ubuntu user account, or even just a new Chrome user profile, none of your old profile's cookies, settings, bookmarks, local storage, etc. is retained and your browser is as good as new - almost.

It still has the same installed plug-ins (like Flash) and still runs on the same operating system and hardware.

You have to know that there are far more possibilities to identify a user/browser/computer on the internet. Please check out https://panopticlick.eff.org/, a free and anonymous online tool provided by the Electronic Frontier Foundation (EFF) that analyzes all data it can get from your browser and shows you how unique these values are amongst all of their visitors. In other words, you will see that your browser could most likely be identified even without any active tracking mechanisms like storing cookies on your device.

---

So as total privacy and anonymity is nearly impossible and also quite unfeasible if you still want to use the websites you visit, what can you do to at least improve your anonymity? Below are a few personal suggestions, so they're not necessarily guaranteed to be unbiased, complete or the most effective.

- First of all, I'd not use Google Chrome. Google is one of the most giant and data-hungry companies you can find, so if you care about privacy, avoid them where possible. Use e.g. Chromium (the open-source project on which Google Chrome is based, but without their proprietary additions) or Firefox.
- The site you probably use most and for the largest diversity of topics is your search engine. Again, better don't use Google but a service that does not track you, like DuckDuckGo.
- Install some add-ons for your browser which allow you to block ads as well as scripts, cookies, requests, etc. from specific domains. I personally like uMatrix and uBlock Origin, which exist both for Firefox and Chrome browsers, but they are quite advanced and have a notable learning curve. E.g. Privacy Badger or Disconnect might be easier to use, but are also less aggressive and less customizable. It is important that you trust those add-ons though. They see every site you visit and can potentially access all data in your browser, so make sure you get reputable and trustworthy ones.
- Use private browsing/incognito mode when necessary. This prevents sites both from accessing cookies and local data of your regular browsing history as well as from permanently storing new stuff. You can also e.g. configure your browser to drop all (but whitelisted) local data when you exit the browser and only always keep stuff for the current session.
- Do more research on the topic. This list can never be complete and there will be changes all the time as well. You might find your own personal favourite configuration that is an optimal compromise for you between anonymity/privacy and usability.